# Azure Resource Graph Explorer :: query Cost Management API

Tags: kql, cost-management, azure-monitor-workbooks, azure-resource-graph, azure-cost-calculation

I have a [Kusto query](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/includes/resource-graph/samples/bytable/resources.md) that can help me list a few resources:

```
ResourceContainers
| where type=='microsoft.resources/subscriptions/resourcegroups' | project name, type  | limit 5
| union  (Resources | project name, type | limit 5)
```

I would like to add for each resource the cost of the last 30 days.

I know I can do that through [Workbooks](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/itops-talk-blog/customize-cost-data-visualizations-with-azure-workbooks-and/ba-p/2387779)  but I don't know how to do that from the Azure Resource Graph Explorer.

I know that form the Azure Resource Graph Explorer I can query the [Azure Advisor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/advisor/resource-graph-samples?tabs=azure-cli), which is something similar to what I want to do.

But how can I reach the Cost Management API?

Comment: It isn't possible to retrieve cost details of each resource using ARG.

Comment: Dammit. OK, thank you @SwathiDhanwada . Should I delete my question? Or do you want to add your reply?

Comment: No, please don't remove question. This is much needed use case for [FinOps](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/fasttrack-for-azure/the-azure-finops-guide/ba-p/3704132).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't possible to retrieve cost details of each resource using ARG as of now.

Comment: Thank you, so what is the alternative for having resources and costs in the same query?

Comment: do both of them separately, and then use the "merge" data source in workbooks to merge the results of the 2 queries (unfortunately the ARM data source only lets you query one resource at a time, so it might not get you want you need if you need MANY calls to arm)